# Force Resultion for Presenter View

Tags: macos, microsoft-powerpoint, projector

We have an issue with a projector where it can only display up to 720p input. It is a 1080p projector and was working before, but the wires may have been run too long in order to conceal them.

The workaround for now is to use the iMac and projector at 720p when display mirroring is enabled, instead of their native 1080p. The problem with this is that PowerPoint turns off display mirroring in Presenter View and everything defaults back to 1080p. So no one is able to give a presentation in Presenter View.

How can I force PowerPoint to present in 720p or stop the resolution from changing?

The setup is OS X 10.8 with PowerPoint 2011.

Comment: Can you confirm/test the cables by temporarily using a shorter one? Also which cable. Analog (e.g. VGA) which degrades with longer cables? Digital (DVI, DP) which should either work or not work? Etc etc.

Comment: @Hennes Yes, I was able to inch the setup towards close enough to run a 20' hdmi cable, that was able to produce the full 1080p picture. The cable job that was installed over the summer uses a proprietary cable type that bridges various connectors, HDMI in this case.

Comment: @Hennes [Image of RapidRun connection](http://i.imgur.com/upFvQiy.jpg). The metal parts you see allow various connection types to run across the wire. We're doing iMac DisplayPort to HDMI adapter > receiver/amp > HDMI > lengthy RapidRun run > HDMI > projector.

Comment: Why can't you just in the "Slide Show" tab, choose the Resolution of 1280×720 (720p) ?

Comment: @harrymc I don't see that option: http://i.imgur.com/4UJr7mN

Comment: Looks like this option was omitted from PowerPoint 2011! Here is how it looks [on PowerPoint 2010](http://i.imgur.com/57Bzwd5.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was actually a simple way to solve this once I reread my question. My settings for Mirrored mode are fine, but extended mode was the problem. In OS X, temporally switching to extended display mode, then setting the resolution to 720p solved the problem.

Now when PowerPoint switches out of Mirroed mode between it uses these settings.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like one cannot set the resolution in PowerPoint 2011.

You might consider using an alternative to PowerPoint 2011 such as the free [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/).

A commercial alternatives is [Keynote](http://www.apple.com/iwork/keynote/) ($19.99).